# Calling outside subs and modules in Template Toolkit without Plugins?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I am trying to call an outside Perl module in a Template Toolkit .tt file. The module I want to use is `Util`, and I want to call `Util::prettify_date`. I was able to include this module using Template Toolkit's plugin interface: I set up the load, new, and error function (as described here: http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin.html), and include it using `[% USE Util %]`.

This works fine, but I was wondering if there's a way to `USE` Perl modules in Template Toolkit without having to plugin-ify them. The main issue with making plugins is that I have to make all the functions in `Util` object-oriented (ie. accepts $self as first argument), which doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `use`ing the module in a [`[% PERL %]`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Template::Manual::Directives#PERL) block?

Now, I personally would write a plugin which relays, say, a `MyOrg::Plugin::Util->prettify_date` to `Util::prettify_date` after getting rid of the first argument. You can automate the creation of these methods as well:

```
my @to_proxy = qw( prettify_date );

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    {
        no strict 'refs';
        for my $sub ( @to_proxy) {
            *{"${class}::${sub}"} = sub {
                my $self = shift;
                return "My::Util::$sub"->( @_ );
            }
        }
    }
    bless {} => $class;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can also pass functions (ie. subroutines) to template like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util ();
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new({
    INCLUDE_PATH  => '.',
});

$tt->process( 'not_plugin.tt', { 
    divider    => sub { '='  x  $_[0]         },
    capitalize => sub { ucfirst $_[0]         },
    sum        => sub { List::Util::sum( @_ ) },
});
```

not_plugin.tt

```
[% divider( 40 ) %]
Hello my name is [% capitalize( 'barry' ) %], how are u today?
The ultimate answer to life is [% sum( 10, 30, 2 ) %]
[% divider( 40 ) %]
```

will produce this:

```
========================================
Hello my name is Barry, how are u today?
The ultimate answer to life is 42
========================================
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, most dangerous way to accomplish this is to use a `[% PERL %]` block and force the evaluation to occur in the `main` namespace.

```
[% PERL %]
package main;
# You can now use any variables and subroutines as though this were in the main namespace
[% END %]
```

This is necessary because the `[% PERL %]` block is [evaluated](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_PERL) in an isolated `Template::Perl` package namespace, which you are overriding with `package main`

The danger comes from your template being able to *write* into the main namespace in addition to reading from it, which can lead to some interesting debug.