# template-toolkit datetime in ISO format as input

Tags: perl, datetime, iso, template-toolkit

Is there an easy way to have template-toolkit accept date/times in ISO 8601 format as input?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Specifically I'm looking for the combined date/time format assuming UTC time:

yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ

and then have TT adjust timezone & formatting based on locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you should use [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) module, and [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) to parse and format (transform from DateTime to string and viceversa.

Comment: Yes but in the spirit of MVC, I'd like to do it wholly within TemplateToolkit.  I came up with a way (see my self-answer which I will post shortly) but not sure it's best.

Comment: At the controller, you can handle this dates to do the work to the view.

Comment: This SO question may helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285441/calling-outside-modules-in-template-toolkit-without-plugins

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I didn't now you could use any Perl module within TT.  Sure would be nice if TT Date plugin accepted ISO dates as input, without having to bloat with yet another module; that would be the ideal answer.  I will accept yours, thanks!

Comment: [DateTime::Format::RFC3339](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::RFC3339) and [DateTime::Format::ISO8601](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::ISO8601) would also do.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work, but it's a bit kludgy:

```
<% USE date %>
...
<% date.format(mydatetime.substr(0,10) _ ' ' _ mydatetime.substr(11,8), '%c', 'en_US') %>
```

Open to other suggestions.  Assumes en_US as locale.

Comment: My answer works a kludge if you're willing to accept less than perfect parsing in exchange for not having to add another Perl module as described in the accepted answer.