# invoke Perl method by text template

Tags: html, perl

Exists there a way to invoke a Perl sub from an incremental text template (HTML5)?
Access of the data context and a bunch of variable works fine, but a sub call is required.

```
<p class="submit">
                [% IF page == "building_add " %]
                <input type="submit" value="[% l.submit %]" id="submit" />
                [% ELSIF page == "building_show" && ( (!auth_done) || (auth_done && check_access_rolebuilding(building_id,auth_user_id))) %]
                <input type="submit" value="[% l.change %]" id="submit" />
                [% END %]
</p>
```

`check_access_rolebuilding` will not be invoked. That's checked via debug output. Any advice?

Comment: If you're using [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/), see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285441/calling-outside-modules-in-template-toolkit-without-plugins) for two solutions.

Comment: parse error :-( unexpected token (>), but your link will be checked out in addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a reference to the subroutine into the hash of variables that you pass into the `process()` method.

```
# Your process() call might not look anything like this.
$tt->process(
  $template_name,
  {
    ... # existing variables
    check_access_rolebuilding => \&check_access_rolebuilding,
  },
) or die $tt->error;
```

Then within the template, you can use the `check_access_rolebuilding()` subroutine by just naming it as you have done in your example..